# Jupter notebook to tex to pdf without cell content

Tags: python, tex, nbconvert

I am not entirely sure whether this is the right forum (tag) for this question, so my apologies if it is wrong. The problem I face is the following:

I am creating a report that I will be genreating for a number of customers. In it I have a number of statitics about product, visualizations, tables etc. those are created using connections of `BigQuery` in GCP and using `python`. In the best of worlds i would tag all computation and data retreival cells with at tag `hide-input`, use jupyter nbconvet and create a pdf-report. Unfortunately, this does not work due to limitations in my environemnt.

However, I can convert my notebook to `*.tex` and then convet that file to a pdf-files. But, in this case, all cells are visible.

Does anyone know how to hide content of a `tex`-file during the conversion to pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the `\iffalse` command? This command is commonly used to create a block of code that LaTeX will ignore.

```
\iffalse
\begin{pythoncode}
# Python code here or the content you want to hide after generating your report or whatever you want to hide!
\end{pythoncode}
\fi
```

Comment: Glad to hear that ^_^

Comment: This is really good because I can create a python script that with introduce this whereever the begin ```\begin{Verbatim}``` and ```\end{verbatim}``` commands appear without loosing the content. The alternative would have been deleting anything inbetween these.